# Square-bracketed numeric-style citation call-outs with round parentheses around years with "dcu" bibliography style

Tags: natbib, harvard-style

I would like to have citations using square brackets [1], while the year in the formatted bib item is surrounded by round parentheses.

[1] Author, T. (2017) *A question*, TeX - LaTEX.

Currently `natbib` uses the same style of brackets around the citation call-outs and around the year.

So if I say:

```
\bibpunct{(}{)}{;}{n}{}{,}
```

I get

(1)
...

[1] Author, T. (2017) *A question*, TeX - LaTEX.

And if I say:

```
\bibpunct{[}{]}{;}{n}{}{,}
```

I get

[1]
...

[1] Author, T. [2017] *A question*, TeX - LaTEX.

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{dcu}
\bibpunct{[}{]}{;}{n}{}{,}

\begin{document}
Some text. \cite{author2017}
\bibliography{bibliography}
\end{document}
```

And the file `bibliography.bib`:

```
@Article{author2017,
  author =   {The Author},
  title =    {A Question},
  journal =  {TeX -- LaTeX},
  year =     2017}
```

Comment: I had the same problem with `agsm` style too. The solution below worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:**

test.tex:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{dcu}
\bibpunct{[}{]}{;}{n}{}{,}

%%%%
% Add these two lines:
%%%%
\def\harvardyearleft{(}
\def\harvardyearright{)}


\begin{document}

Some text. \cite{author2017}

\bibliography{bibliography}

\end{document}
```

bibliography.bib:

```
@Article{author2017,
  author =   {The Author},
  title =    {A Question},
  journal =  {TeX -- LaTeX},
  year =     2017}
```

**Old answer:**

If you don't have real many citations you can use:

test.tex:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{dcu}
\bibpunct{}{}{;}{n}{}{,}

\let\oldcite=\cite
\def\cite#1{[\oldcite{#1}]}

\begin{document}

Some text. \cite{author2017}

\bibliography{bibliography}

\end{document}
```

bibliography.bib:

```
@Article{author2017,
  author =   {The Author},
  title =    {A Question},
  journal =  {TeX -- LaTeX},
  year =     {(2017)}}
```

Output is exactly what you want... But you have to change all your citations in bibliography.bib file.

Comment: A quick fix, but I have a lot of bibliography entries and this solution is not sustainable.  Thanks.

Comment: @vivian I found a solution by accident! But it works with current format.